# Print smallest integer from file using awk custom function?

Tags: awk, text-processing

`awk` function looks like this in a file name `fun.awk`:

```
{
print small()
}
function small()

{
a[NR]=$0

smal=0

for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
if( a[i]<a[i+1])

smal=a[i]

else

smal=a[i+1]

}
return smal
}
```

The contents of `awk.write`:

```
1
23 
32
```

The `awk` command is:

```
awk -f fun.awk awk.write
```

It gives me no result? Why?

Comment: Please can you add some indentation to make this easier to read?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.  In awk, one approach might be:

```
NR == 1 { 
    small = $0 
}
$0 < small {
    small = $0
}
END {
    print small
}
```

which simply simply sets `small` to the smallest integer we've seen so far on each line, and prints it at the end.  (Note: you need to start with a initializing `small` on the first line.

A simpler approach might just be to sort the lines as numbers with `sort`, and pick the first one.